# Angular not displaying firestore data when deployed

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When angular deployed to firebase, data from firestore not being displayed, localhost running fine, what could be the problem

Comment: Does it print any error in the console? Paste it in the question.

Comment: Please update your code with how may environments you have, which command you used to build your app.