# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after Angular site deployed to Firebase Hosting (localhost...?)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to evaluate an admin template from angular-templates.io and the production build works fine. I upload to Firebase Hosting specifying dist/browser (created during production build) but when I load the firebase app in the browser, it just shows "Loading...". The error it gives is:

> main.43059628ad5e08be77bb.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
>       at R (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at R (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (main.43059628ad5e08be77bb.js:1)
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at e.runTask (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at d (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at _ (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>
> vp @ main.43059628ad5e08be77bb.js:1
>   localhost:8000/assets/data/ng2_charts.json:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> main.43059628ad5e08be77bb.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
>       at R (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at R (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (main.43059628ad5e08be77bb.js:1)
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at e.runTask (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at d (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>       at _ (polyfills.45eead93d001664270af.js:1)
>   vp @ main.43059628ad5e08be77bb.js:1
>
> localhost:8000/assets/data/extended_table.json:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

It seems to be saying it can't find two files: ng2_charts.json & extended_table.json at localhost:8000/assets/data. Those two files do exist under dist/browser/assets/data, but why is it searching **localhost**?

I haven't seen anything in the documentation about requiring a configuration change before deployment and I went through the instructions in angular-templates.io

This is literally each step I've performed:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

copy source files from downloaded zip (after checking unblock in properties)

```
npm i
npm audit fix
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

creates dist/browser folder and runs fine

```
npm i @angular/fire firebase --save
npm i angularfire2
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase init
firebase deploy
```

Open the firebase app in the browser

It seems like there is a configuration step I missed, but I haven't seen that listed in the documentation anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I checked SO to try and find an answer, but these are the closest I've found:

[My react project not working after deploy to firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718983/my-react-project-not-working-after-deploy-to-firebase-hosting)

[Angular 6.0 firebase hosting deploy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360477/angular-6-0-firebase-hosting-deploy-not-working)

[Angular not displaying firestore data when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396838/angular-not-displaying-firestore-data-when-deployed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! Had to update two files (**server.ts** and **src\environments\environment.prod.ts**

**server.ts**
From

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

To

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Node Express server listening on https://<myfirebaseproject>.firebaseapp.com:${PORT}`);
});
```

and **src\environments\environment.prod.ts**

from

```
exports.environment = {
   production: true,
   BASE_URL: 'http://mylocalhost:8008'
};
```

to

```
exports.environment = {
   production: true,
   BASE_URL: 'https://<myfirebaseproject>.firebaseapp.com'
};
```

If this was documented, can someone please comment for my reference? Would have been really helpful if angular-templates.io had mentioned it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I answered my own question but am not sure how to mark it answered? Believe I have to upvote first but cannot upvote my own post...?